# Changing a property of something in XAML from a button click

Tags: wpf, xaml

Given the following bit of XAML

```
<Border Name="Brder" Visibility="Visible" Width="10" Height="10" Background="Red"></Border>
<Button Content="Hide"></Button>
```

How can I set the button click to change the visibility of the border (not using code behind)?

I know it's trivial in code behind and the routed click event only seems to allow storyboard manipulation?

Thanks

Comment: You may want to read more about MVVM, as it's the cleanest way to start using WPF with less reliance on code-behind.  The basic idea is that the button is connected to a Command on a ViewModel class, which then has logic to set a property as to whether the border should be visible.  The Border's visibility is bound to that property, so if the property changes, the border will change appropriately.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx

Comment: @Dan - I use MVVM regularly - but sometimes there is functionality that exists on the view and should be unknown to the vm - hence the question :)

Comment: could you give an example?  The example you gave seems to fit most naturally with behavior through the VM, so I'd like to better understand what kind of behavior should be unknown to the VM.

Comment: I've got several buttons that show / hide various parts of the UI (screen estate can be a problem with the size of some our customers monitors :). I don't want the vm to care about specific ui functions that wouldn't translate if I connected a different view to the same vm. Hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you change the Button to a ToggleButton you can bind visibility to IsChecked of the ToggleButton using XAML only. Also remember that Expanders support this behavior as well and you can laways style them if you don't like the default look.